# Create session on consuming login with api on laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an api that has a method to start and I am calling it from a frontend project.

In the front end project I use Guzzle to make the call via post to the api and login, from which I get back a json with the user data and a jwt token.

But when I receive the token as I manage the session, I must create a session and save the token, since the laravel to authenticate I need a model user and have a database, which of course I do not have in this backend because I call the api to log in, which brings a token and user data, then as I manage it from the backend, I'm a little lost there.

```
            $api = new Api();
            $response = $api->loginapi(['user'=>'wings@test.com','password'=>'123']);
```

Because here I could not do Auth::login($user) to generate the session.
Because I don't have here the database because the login is done from the api.

There I call the api, of which the answer is the token, but how do I manage it from here, creating a session? saving the token?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With api, you don't usually manage a session. usually, you'd call something like

```
Auth::attempt([
    'email' => 'me@example.com',
    'password' => 'myPassword'
]);
```

If the credentials are correct, laravel will include a Set-Cookie header in response, and, that is how you authenticate with api. Via an auth cookie. You don't need to do anything else.

Let's show you how:

```
//AuthController.php
public function login(Request $request) {
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt($validatedData)){
        return ['success' => 'true'];
    }

    else{
        return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'Email or password Invalid'];
    }
}

public function currentUser (){
    return Auth::user();
}
```

Now, the APi file

```
Route::post('/login', ['App\Http\Controllers\AuthController', 'login']);
Route::get('/current_user', ['App\Http\Controllers\AuthController', 'currentUser']);
```

Now if you make a call to `/api/current_user` initially, you'll get null response since you're not currently logged in. But once you make request to `/api/login` and you get a successful response, you are now logged in. Now if you go to `/api/current_user`, you should see that you're already logged in.

**Important ::**

If you are using fetch, you need to [include credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) if you're using something other than fetch, check out how to use credentials with that library or api

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the API to authenticate and then use the SessionGuard to create session including the remember_me handling.

This is the default login controller endpoint for logging in. You don't want to change this, as it makes sure that user's do not have endless login attempts (protects for brut-force attacks) and redirects to your current location.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
        $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        if ($request->hasSession()) {
            $request->session()->put('auth.password_confirmed_at', time());
        }

        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

The core happens when we try to "attemptLogin" at

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->boolean('remember')
    );
}
```

When using the SessioGurad (which is default) the method `attemptLogin` fires a couple of events, checks if the user has valid credentials (by hashing the password and matching it with db) and then logs the user in, including the remember me functionality.

Now, if you don't care about events, you can just check from your API if the credentials match and then use the login method from the guard. This will also handle the remember me functionality. Something like this:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->input($this->username());
    $password = $request->input('password');

    $result = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::post(env('YOUR_API_DOMAIN') . '/api/v0/login' , [
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    ])->json();

    if(empty($result['success'])){
       return false;
    }

    // Maybe you need to create the user here if the login is for the first time?
    $user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->first();
    $this->guard()->login(
        $user, $request->boolean('remember')
    );

    return true;
}
```